# Convert in R from numeric to char without changing value

Tags: r, type-conversion, char, format, format-truncation

I have a data table extracted from SQL Server, using sqlQuery and it looks like this:

| PK   | Value1 | Value2 |

|:---- |:------:| ------:|

| A01  | Descrp | 0.062  |

By default, Value1 is char and Value2 is numeric.
I would like to transform Value2 to char and to obtain the same result.

I tried to use: df$Value2 <- as.character(df$Value2), but it transform 0.062 to 0.061999998986721

Any ideas on how to keep 0.062, but as a char column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.061999998986721` is the full value. You could use `round` or `signif` within `as_character` depending on how the other numbers are formatted. For the example provided:

```r
> as.character(round(0.061999998986721, 3))
[1] "0.062"

> as.character(signif(0.061999998986721, 2))
[1] "0.062"
```

Comment: thank you! it is working. I still have one question: if you have in the same column values like: 0.062 and 0.00000062 and 0.62 (different precision after point, how do we handle this situation)?

Comment: Whats your desired output then?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a constant number of digits:

```
format(df$Value2, digits = 3)
```